# create custom variable for custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, variables

Is it impossible to create a custom variable, such as {{var customer.getName()}} in a custom module and use it?

Comment: Where do you want to use the variables?

Comment: any where ... is it importent?
i create an column in db that saved sms body ...and i want user be able to use same customer attribute such as customer name